# Is there a way to post a photo on Facebook on Android without using the Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

I've removed the Facebook app from my smartphone (Android) because it's a time suck, but I'd still like to be able to post photos of my food (because yes, I *am* that guy).

There used to be a way to email a photo to secretname@m.facebook.com and have it post, but it appears they've since removed that feature.

iOS can do it because it has Facebook integration built in, but I'm on Android.

I tried the Facebook Moments app, but it doesn't appear to post photos on your timeline.  I looked for other third party apps, but couldn't find anything.

Any other options I have?

Comment: Does it work through Facebook's mobile site in your browser? Or is there a specific workflow you're trying to achieve that makes the browser unsuitable?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the mobile website.  I want an app that quickly posts photos to my Facebook timeline and nothing else.

Comment: I am also sad they removed the email option.

Comment: Yea email would have been perfect for this!  I should write my own email gateway..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an IFTTT account and connect your Facebook account to it (ifttt.com).
Then you install the app from play store (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifttt.ifttt).
Here's the link to my applet for this same purpose: https://ifttt.com/applets/51211438d-upload-a-photo-from-url-to-user-s-photos 
Or, you can create the applet yourself:

1. go to My Applets -> click on the '+' icon.
2. for '+this' search for and choose the 'Camera Widget'. In trigger, there is only one, 'any new photo'. Pick that
3. for '+that' search for and choose 'Facebook'. In 'select action', choose 'Upload a photo from URL'
4. On the next screen, you can modify how it is posted. Play around a bit with the message until it is to your liking. You can also set an album to store the photos.
5. Once you're done, tap on the checkmark in the top right corner and click 'Finish'.
6. you then go back to your home screen and add an IFTTT widget. Once you drop the widget on your home screen, you will be asked to choose the applet. Choose the one you just created.
7. Now, when you want to take a picture, tap on the new icon. It will open the camera and you can take the picture. It will be directly shared to your Facebook timeline.

Comment: Interesting solution!  I'll have to mess around with this a bit later..